# Call random player actions

Tags: java

```
public void onResult(QuestionAdResult questionAdResult) {
                if (questionAdResult.wasCorrect()) {
                    // Additional Exp +5
                    // Additional HP  +5
                    Hero.instance.earnExp(5);
                    Hero.instance.earnHP(5);
                    //
                } else {
                    // Stuff
                }
            }
```

So I'm building a game and it has 2 methods.

```
Hero.instance.earnExp(5);
Hero.instance.earnHP(5);
```

I can uncomment either one for whichever specific action, but I'd like the actions to be random so it does either or, instead of having to comment one out. How would I go about it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import java.util.Random;

```
public void onResult(QuestionAdResult questionAdResult) {

    Random random = new Random();
    int expOrHealth = random.nextInt(2);
    if (questionAdResult.wasCorrect()) {
        if (expOrHealth == 0)
        {
        // Additional Exp +5
        }
        if (expOrHealth == 1)
        {
             // Additional HP  +5
        }

        Hero.instance.earnExp(5);
        Hero.instance.earnHP(5);
        //
    } else {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I love you. You should know that.